# Capture POST results to array

Tags: php, html

I am currently printing a dynamic list with input fields on a form. It looks like the below,

```
<?php foreach ($Months as $month) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $month;?></td>
        <td><input value="0" type="text" class="form-control" id="MonthValue" name="MonthValue[]"></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

My question is, how do I now capture the users input back into an array when the form is posted ?

Comment: `foreach( $_POST['MonthValue'] AS $index => $value ) {...}` where `$index` will be a zero-based numeric index of which item in the list, and `$value` will be the value entered by the user.

Comment: FYI, you're going to end up with multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. You probably don't want that

Comment: _"how do I now capture the users input back into an array"_ <- it already is an array in `$_POST['MonthValue']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in `$_POST['MonthValue']` ; the $_POST array contains indices for each of your form fields' names.

Note: you might want to use a value other than `0` (I suggest `1`); in PHP, `0` can easily be mistaken for `FALSE`.

Comment: Indeed on `0` vs `FALSE` (vs `NULL` vs `""`) - may even be worth a comment on `===` vs `==`....

Comment: How would I capture the array using javascript ? currently im using document.getElementById('MonthValue').value. It only returns the first value and not an array ?

Comment: @5abre when did this become a JavaScript problem? In any case, see my comment on your question about the duplicate `id` attributes. You'll want to use something repeatable like a `class` instead

Comment: Stand down Phil, no need for that.
For those it may help... capturing the array using javascript looks something like this "$("input[name='MonthValue[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get()"